# "Ich weiß nicht" vs "Ich weiße"

Tags: verb

I'm totally new to the German language, so a question came up to my mind to which I could not find any answer. As far as I know, we say `ich weiße` in the present tense, then why do we remove the last letter `e` when we say `ich weiß nicht`?

Comment: It is **not** *ich weiße* (except if you want to say *I whiten*.)

Comment: What you might have heard was something like "Ich weise den Weg" - "I show/point at the way" or "Das weise ich zurück" - "I refuse/disclaim/reject that"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*»I know«* translates to *»ich weiß«*, but we have the verb

> [weißen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/weiszen) = mit weißer Tünche anstreichen *(to whitewash)*

and here

> ich weiße = ich streiche mit weißer Tünche an *(I'm whitewashing)*

is correct.

Also valid:

> Ich Weiße habe unter Schwarzen nie Probleme.
>   *(I as a white woman never have problems among black people.)*

Comment: so then what is the `Infinitiv` form of the `ich weiß` ? that is what had led me to this misunderstanding, and Thank you

Comment: I think I've already found that , `wissen` ,

Comment: "Wissen" belongs to a class of verbs called "preterie-presents". This means that the present form once used to be a preterite. The preterite of a strong verb does not have a -e ending (Compare Ich gehe/ich ging). This explains the lacking -e ending."Wissen" stems from an indo-european root meaning "to see". "Ich weiß" originates from a verb form that meant "I saw/I have seen". (Compare to latin videre "to see")

Answer (score 11):

You are talking about two different verbs:

### weißen

in English: to white, to whiten, to blanch (something)

> Ich weiße. Du weißt. Er weißt. Wir weißen. Ihr weißt. Sie weißen.
>   I whiten. You whiten. He whitens. We whiten. You whiten. They whiten.

Negation:

> Ich weiße nicht. Du weißt nicht. ...
>   I don't whiten. You don't whiten. ...

This word is derived in both languages, German and English, from the color white/Weiß, which has the same Indo-European root with the meaning »bright, shining«.

---

### wissen

in English: to know

> Ich weiß. Du weißt. Er weiß. Wir wissen. Ihr wisst. Sie wissen.
>   I know. You know. He knows. We know. You know. They know.

Negation:

> Ich weiß nicht. Du weißt nicht.
>   I don't know. You don't know.

The German verb *wissen* derives from the same Indo-European root like the English adjective *visual*: Something you can see.

The English verb *to know* has a root with the original meaning "perceive a thing to be identical with another".

---

Both German verbs (*weißen* and *wissen*) are equal only for 2<sup>nd</sup> Person singular (*Du weißt*). But since their meaning is so different, it's very hard to imagine any context where it is unclear which one is meant.